# Shiny progress bar completed before do.call() is terminated

Tags: r, progress-bar, shiny, do.call

I am trying to implement a shiny app that calls a function with a set of arguments. Such function returns a plot which is rendered with renderPlot(). A progress bar is generated to keep the user updated.

I am particularly interested in calling this function and its arguments using `do.call`, as my final goal is to wrap it up as a shiny module. However, the progress bar is "completed" before the plot gets the chance to be generated. Only after the progress bar disappears, the plots are rendered. I assume this is caused by the fact that I am trying to use `do.call()` to handle the plotting function. I have created here a simplified version of the problem:

```
ui <- fixedPage(
  wellPanel(
    plotOutput("plot")
    , fluidPage(actionButton("Btn", "plot", class = "btn-primary"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$Btn, {

    message("button triggered")

    withProgress(message = "Progress bar"
                   , detail ='Rendering plot...'
                   , value = 0,{

                     # pausa
                     Sys.sleep(1)               
                     # updade progress bar
                     setProgress(0.5)

                     output$plot <- renderPlot({
                       # plot to render
                       do.call(plot, list(1:10, 11:20))  
                       # pause
                       do.call(Sys.sleep, list(2))
                     })

                     # update progress to complete status
                     setProgress(1)
                   })



    showNotification("DONE!", duration = 5, closeButton =  TRUE, type = "warning")

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am expecting the progress bar to be completed AFTER the plot is generated and visualized. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I've added two options, one with `shinycssloaders` if you're not aware and another fixing your existing code to sync plot and bar.

```
library(shinycssloaders)

ui <- fixedPage(
  wellPanel(
    #withSpinner(plotOutput("plot")) #uncomment if you need to use the pkg
    plotOutput("plot")
    , fluidPage(actionButton("Btn", "plot", class = "btn-primary"))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$Btn, {

    message("button triggered")

    withProgress(message = "Progress bar"
                 , detail ='Rendering plot...'
                 , value = 0,{

                   # pausa
                   Sys.sleep(1)               
                   # updade progress bar
                   setProgress(0.5)



                   # update progress to complete status
                   setProgress(1)
                 })

    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      # plot to render
      do.call(plot, list(1:10, 11:20))  
      # pause
      #do.call(Sys.sleep, list(2))
    })


    showNotification("DONE!", duration = 5, closeButton =  TRUE, type = "warning")

  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```